# PHP OOP architecture question (OOP against Roles)

Tags: php, oop

There are users with different privileges in the system. They privileges are hierarchical

```
class User{//abstract user not logged in
    //function signIn(){}
}

class Guest extends User{

}

class FullUser extends Guest{
    static function signUp(){}//create an account
    function signOut(){}
}

class Moderator extends FullUser{
          function edit(){}//some new method introduced here,never introduced before
}

class Admin extends Moderator{
           //can do everything
}

//can use
FullUser::signUP()
```

Is my architecture good?
Can you advice me anything else? 
I was wondering which is the best way to create a user - write a constructor? Or let it be a "factory" function.

```
function signIn($username, $password)
```

I'm new to OOP in php, so I accept wise advices, links, etc.

---

**EDIT**:
I'm planning to use this role - checking system:

```
if(!method_exists($user->addComment())) die('Access denied')
```

What do you think of it?

---

**EDIT 2:**
should I create a role table with ROLE in axis X and METHOD in axis Y?

```
            comment | post |  editPost | kill
guest          0        0        0         0
fullUser       1        0        0         0
moderator      1        1        1         0
admin          1        1        1         1
```

And later I should write something like this

```
function addComment($user){
if(!$ROLES [$this->$role][__FUNCTION__])return;
....
}
```

Is that better than OOP, wise programmers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Roles are definitely the way to go.

You can do something simple like letting each user have a `public $role` attribute where $role is just a number (e.g. 9 = admin, 6 = fulluser, 3 = guest).

The database table would look like this

```
Users
id  username    password    role
1   admin       somePass    9
2   someUser    somePass    3
```

In the code you do stuff like ´if ($user->role >= 9)´.

If you want, you can have a role table instead of using just numbers - like this:

```
Roles
id  role
1   admin
2   fulluser
3   user
4   guest
```

You could also make it more advanced where one user can have an array of roles.

Comment: Is the EDIT 2 in my post an extension of your method?

Answer (score 3):

I'd be more inclined to set privileges based on a role based system. It's somewhat more flexible in that a user can be associated with 1 or more roles, and depending on those roles they can perform different actions.

Comment: Could you please describe the "role-based-syslem" on my simple example?

Answer (score 3):

I'd define a role based schema too.

First, let's create a class for user credentials:

```
class CUserCredentials {

    public 
        $orgID,
        $ordSubID,
        $password;

    // or protected instance variables an accessors

} // CUserCredentials
```

In our case, users identify by  an organisational ID [a company number], a number relative to it orgID [e.g. his employee number] and a password.

The process, of testing credentials against a certain role gets encapsulated by an abstract class:

```
class CAbstractRoleVerifier {

    // return 
    public static function hasRoleUsingUserCredentials( CUserCredentials $cred );

}
```

The method *hasRoleUsingUserCredentials()* verifies credentials against 'whatever', e.g. a database table.

Then we define an abstract role manager, which is the template for a specific implementation:

```
class CAbstractRoleManager {

    static protected 
        $possibleRoles;

    // The standard role
    protected $primaryRole;

    // The other roles he is able to use
    protected $userrRoles;

    // verifies all defined roles
    public function verifyAllRoles( CUserCredentials $cred );

}
```

While the above class is part of our framework, our application needs to implement a concrete Role Manager, e.g. like this:

```
class CMyRoleManager extends CAbstractRoleManager {

    // these two are nomal roles
    const ROLE_USER     = 1;
    const ROLE_MANAGER  = 2;

    // this is a special role, which allows to 
    const ROLE_ADMIN    = 3;

    protected 
        $userRoles;

    public function __construct() {


        // prepare CMyRoleVerifierUser, CMyRoleVerifierManager as subclasses of the             
        // above class          
        self::$possibleRoles = array(
            self::ROLE_USER     => new CMyRoleVerifierUser(),
            self::ROLE_USER     => new CMyRoleVerifierManager(),
            self::ROLE_ADMIN    => new CMyRoleVerifierAdmin(),
            ); 

        // Initially, user has no role
        $this->userRoles = array();

        $this->mainRole = FALSE;


    }

    public function verifyAllRoles( CUserCredentials $cred ) {

        foreach( self::$possibleRoles as $roleID => $verifier ) {

            if ( $verifier->hasRoleUsingUserCredentials( $cred ) ) {

                $this->userRoles[ $roleID ] = $roleID; 
            }

        }

    }

    public function hasRole( $aRoleID ) {

        return isset( $this->userRoles[ $roleID ] );

    }

}
```

Note, how the process of verifying the role set and the process of of verifying a specific role are separated in different classes.

While one could use a class / subclass design, I prefer this design. It allows to keep a set of roles, which might have whatever relation, not only a ROLE_MANAGER is allowed to to all of ROLE_USER *plus* some other operations.

In my case, ROLE_ADMIN is a special role. If user verifies against ROLE_ADMIN, he sees certain administrative features enabled. Besides other special operations, he is allowed to temporarily behave as if he *is* the other role. 
$this->mainRole not fully implemented here

Comment: Could you please have a look at my version of role based schema?

Comment: I'm happy to provide a base implementation tomorrow. Today, it's a bit late, 1:22 at night ;-)

Comment: could you please explain your idea in afew words?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, I tend to use a bitwise permission system, where permissions are set based on individual needs and can be overridden by a group permission, where for instance, you can see if the user has the permission, if not, see if the group they belong to has it, etc. This seems to be pretty flexible in terms of adding new features and scalability.

Your method will work though. As far as the constructor, I would probably not override it and make it log the user in, get their stats and permissions, etc, and make sure to call this on every new page. Then create simple functions, such as class::listPermissions, etc, that all use parent::function, such as parent::listPermissions. This will help with inheritance, for instance in my example, listing permissions for the admin class will call Admin::listPermissions, FullUser::listPermissions, Guest::listPermissions, so they get all of the permissions they inherit.

I generally don't have much luck with class based systems, but I have seen them in action before.

Answer (score 2):

I think your inheritance hierarchy is a bit messed up. From what I can see it looks something like:

```
User // abstract
    Guest // anonymous and can't do anything
        FullUser // can sign up
                Admin // can do everything
```

In other words, `Guest`s are users, `FullUser`s are `Guest`s, `Admin`s are `FullUser`s and therefore `Admin`s are also `Guest`s. I think I can see what you are doing - incrementally giving more privileges further down the inheritance hierarchy. However, the result is that you will have a high degree of coupling on the concrete classes that extend your `User` class, and you will completely miss out on one of OOP's greatest benefits - polymorphism.

A number of other posters have suggested using Roles instead, which is fine. You could also do it with inheritance, where `User` is an abstract class that defines the abstract methods `signIn` and `signOut`, and different subclasses such as `AdminUser` and `GuestUser` implement completely different behaviour for these methods - e.g. no behaviour for `signOut` for a `Guest`.

Comment: Will I loose polymorphism? Suppose I write `$moderator->addComment()` addComment is defined in `FullUser` class

Comment: Reading your second paragraph - that's an object model too! It polymorphical. What is a role system? Is that based on an array? as arex1337 proposed?

Comment: You lose polymorphism the moment you need to reference a specific concrete class rather than the base class.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring database design, you should probably have only one User class instead of having an inheritance system of more and less powerful users - this can easily change. And sometimes you might want a less powerful user to be able to do something a more powerful user can't.

Let your User objects have one or more roles. Then do stuff like this:

```
if ($user->isAdmin()) {
    //
}
```

Comment: Yes, your method works if an ierarchy breaks due to some new customer requirements, and it's easy to change my ROLES table.
OOP way sucks in this situation

Comment: There's nothing non-OOP with my method. If you want to represent the roles that users have as classes, you're welcome to do so.